# Stein manifold homotopic to wedge of two Stein manifolds

Tags: gn.general-topology, complex-geometry, stein-manifolds

I am not very conversant with Stein structure on a manifold so this may be a very silly question. Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Stein manifolds of dimension $n$, inside $\mathbb{C}^N$. Take $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ and consider a line joining $x$ and $y$. Now if we thicken the line so that everywhere the dimension matches, is the new manifold, Stein?

Basically, I want to construct a Stein manifold $Z$, that has the homotopy type of wedge of $X$ and $Y$.

The problem I faced in CW complexes of dimension 2. Can Gompf's theorem be stated similarly to Eliashberg's theorem? i.e. Can we say a real oriented 4-manifold is Stein if it carries an almost complex structure and if there exists a proper Morse function with the index of critical points \leq 2?

If the above fact is true then only I can take a wedge and build the desired Stein manifold in a given dimension. My approach is to build via taking a local neighborhood of the wedge of CW complex embedded in C^n (one CW having dimension 2 and other of dimension 3) and defining the proper Morse function on the neighborhood. I don't want to use handle body theory.

Comment: How do you make your joining construction holomorphic?

Comment: I don't have an answer to that. Is there a way to get a Stein manifold Z, that has the homotopy type of wedge of X and Y?

Comment: Question is already answered in previous post by same author https://mathoverflow.net/a/401205/81055

Comment: I am concerned with the following fact: If X is Stein and homotopic to a tame CW-complex of dimension 2 say X' and if Y is Stein which is homotopic to a CW complex (finite-dimensional finite CW complex) say Y' (where the dimension of Y'=n \geq 3). Now if I consider wedge of X' and Y',  whether I can get a Stein manifold of diemension n. I am little worried in dimension 2 as Eliashberg's result was true for dimension >2 and Gomph's result was based on handle body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a Stein space which has homotopy type of suspension of another Stein space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/401198/how-to-get-a-stein-space-which-has-homotopy-type-of-suspension-of-another-stein)

Comment: The problem with this solution lies in CW complexes of dimension 2. Can Gompf's theorem be stated similarly to Eliashberg's theorem? i.e. Can we say a real oriented 4-manifold is Stein if it carries an almost complex structure and if there exists a proper Morse function with the index of critical points \leq 2?

Comment: @BenMcKay If the above fact is true then only I can take a wedge and build the desired Stein manifold in a given dimension. My approach is to build via taking a local neighborhood of the wedge of CW complex embedded in C^n and defining the proper Morse function on it. I don't want to use handle body theory.